# HTML5 realtime streaming video from Raspberry

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, gstreamer

I'm trying to make a live stream from a Raspberry camera available on a HTML5 webpage. As the raspberry is on the inside of a firewall, I would like to stream it to an outside server, and this server should be able to supply the streams to the webpage.

I'm able to get the stream from the Raspberry and stream it with Gstreamer to an external server like this:

Raspberry:

```
sudo raspivid -t 0 -b 5500000 -n -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink port=5000 host=EXT_SERVER_IP
```

or use videotest signal instead of Raspberry:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink port=5000 host=EXT_SERVER_IP
```

External server (display on monitor):

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

or, External server (make stream available using tcpserver on port 5001):

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! tcpserversink host=EXT_SERVER_IP port=5001
```

Now i have a few problems:

1. I need the stream to be a format compatible for different browsers (but I would be happy to just make it work in Chrome for a start).
2. I need the stream(s) to be served to the webpage using some http request/response on some specified ports. Gstreamer does not seem to be able to do this.

The transfer using gstreamer from Raspberry to external server is fast and almost without lag, this must also be the case for the web presentation. The lag must be below 0.5 seconds for this application (as voice is transmitted over another media without any lag).

My web page currently looks like this:

```
<video id="video" autoplay="autoplay" controls>
    <source src="http://EXT_SERVER_IP:5005" type="video/webm" codecs="vp8.0, vorbis">
    <source src="http://EXT_SERVER_IP:5006" type="video/ogg" codecs="theora, vorbis">
    <source src="http://EXT_SERVER_IP:5007" type="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2">
    <source src="http://EXT_SERVER_IP:5008" type="html" codecs="vp8.0, vorbis">
    You browser doesn't support element video.
</video>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

-- UPDATE --

This project seems to be a good start.

https://github.com/jacksonliam/mjpg-streamer

But i still need the stream to be available outside the router/firewall, and would like to do this by transmitting the stream to an outside server.
I know portforwarding is an option, but this requires the camera(s) to have an static internal ip, and router configuration, and I'm not sure any of this is possible.

Comment: I wrote a h264 player (that can use the raspivid raw h264 stream) for the web, take a look https://github.com/131/h264-live-player

Answer (score -2):

You want to use [WebRTC with UV4L](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/news/article.php?storyid=174) for HTML5 real-time audio/video streaming.

Comment: It might be useful to summarize the article in case it gets removed. Thanks.

Comment: And this is now the case in 2018.